# Loading the GoogleMaps API and populating table with javascript function with pagination

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, google-maps-api-3

I have set up a flask project that should allow the user to create adventures which also get a location (latitude and longitude) attached to them which is stored in the database.

Now I want to give the user the option view all the adventures that have been created in a table that is searchable with a searchbar on top. There also should be a map that has markers for each adventures location on the current page placed in it. I want to integrate the pagination because of the amount of data that would be present in a deployed application.

However I can not display the map because the initMap function is not recognized. Furthermore the pagination aspect of my table also does not work as expected.

This is the route that I have defined.

```
@main.route('/searchAdventure', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def searchAdventure():
    load_dotenv()
    api_key = os.getenv('API_KEY')
    #Get page and limit from query parameteres with default values
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    limit = request.args.get('limit', 10, type=int)

    #use paginate instead of all to get the subset of adventures
    pagination = Adventure.query.paginate(page=page, per_page = limit, error_out=False)
    adventures = [adventure.to_dict() for adventure in pagination.items]

    latitudes = [adventure['latitude'] for adventure in adventures]
    longitudes = [adventure['longitude'] for adventure in adventures]
    
    if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
        print('ajax request')
        return jsonify(adventures)    

    return render_template('searchAdventures.html', adventures = adventures, api_key = api_key,  latitudes=latitudes, longitudes =longitudes)
```

This is the searchAdventures.html.html template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<style>
    .map-container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>

{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-10">
                <h3 class="text-center mb-4">Adventures</h3>
                <!-- Add the input field for search -->
                <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchBar()" placeholder="Search for adventures...">
                <!-- Move the map container here -->
                <div class="map-container" id="map"></div>
                <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ api_key }}&libraries=maps,places&v=beta&callback=initMap"></script>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-light-bordered-hover" id="adventureTable">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Title</th>
                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                            <th scope="col">Dates</th>
                            <th scope="col">People Wanted</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="adventureBody">
                        {% for adventure in adventures %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{adventure['title']}}</td>
                            <td>{{adventure['type']}}</td>
                            <td>{{ adventure['startdate'] }} - {{ adventure['enddate'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ adventure['people_wanted'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ adventure['description'] }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <!-- Adventures will be appended here-->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
<script>
    var latitudes = JSON.parse('{{ latitudes|safe }}');
    var longitudes = JSON.parse('{{ longitudes|safe }}');
    var adventures = JSON.parse('{{ adventures|tojson|safe }}');

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: parseFloat(latitudes[0]), lng: parseFloat(longitudes[0]) },
        zoom: 12
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < adventures.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: { lat: parseFloat(latitudes[i]), lng: parseFloat(longitudes[i]) },
                map: map,
                title: adventures[i]['title'],
                adventureId: adventures[i]['id']
            });
        }
    }
    var page = 2;
    var limit = 10;

    function loadAdventures(scrolling = false) {
        console.log('loading adventures');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/searchAdventures',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { page: page, limit: limit },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var tbody = $('#adventureBody');

                if (!scrolling) {
                    // Clear the existing table if not scrolling
                    tbody.empty();
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var adventure = data[i];
                    var tr = $('<tr>');
                    tr.append('<td>' + adventure['title'] + '</td>');
                    tr.append('<td>' + adventure['type'] + '</td>');
                    tr.append('<td>' + adventure['startdate'] + ' - ' + adventure['enddate'] + '</td>');
                    tr.append('<td>' + adventure['peoplewanted'] + '</td>');
                    tr.append('<td>' + adventure['description'] + '</td>');
                    tbody.append(tr);
                }
                page++;
            }
        });
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        console.log('scrolling');
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
            loadAdventures(true); // Pass true to indicate scrolling
        }
    });

    loadAdventures();


    function searchBar() {
            // Declare variables
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById('myInput');
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById('adventureTable');
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

            // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0]; // Change the index based on the column you want to search
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = '';
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my base.html template that each page extends.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Adventure Buddies</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Adventure Buddies</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenuHeroA"
                    aria-controls="navbarMenuHeroA" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenuHeroA">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.user_adventures') }}">Your Adventures</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.profile') }}">Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('auth.signup') }}">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="hero bg-primary text-white flex-grow-1">
        <div class="container text-center my-auto">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

I always get the same error indicating that the callback is not possible because the function is not found: Uncaught (in promise) InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
at _.yj (js?key=API_KEY&libraries=maps,places&v=beta&callback=initMap:206:368)
at lca (js?key=API_KEY&libraries=maps,places&v=beta&callback=initMap:293:462)
at js?key=API_KEY&libraries=maps,places&v=beta&callback=initMap:293:15.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You have shared your API key with the world. You should revoke it as soon as possible and create a new one.